# C# - I can't use anything in Toolbox

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, toolbox

I installed the Community 2015 version of Visual Studio after I uninstalled the Enterprise 2015 version.
Now i have this problem that I can't use the features of Toolbox. I couldn't find a solution to this.
There's an image telling what's my problem.

[image]
<sub>(source: [kepfeltoltes.hu](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/160629/toolb_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png))</sub>

This project was fully working and even the Toolbox was working on the Enterprise version. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Try this : https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18560

Comment: @Stanley Okay, now the "All Windows Forms" tab and the tabs I used in the Enterprise version are working, I guess the others aren't working because I'm working on a Windows Forms Application. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

The controls will not be visible or will be disabled if the they are not compatible with the project type you are working with.

In this case, *I am just assuming*, Windows Forms controls on WPF or something else.